# Storing React.js state in component owner

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I have my component owner:

```
var React = require('react');
var Backbone = require('backbone');

var GlobalMessage = require('./shared/global-message.jsx');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            global_message: {
                message: 'error',
                type: ''
            }
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        Backbone.on('global-message', function(data) {
            this.setState({
                global_message: data
            });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <GlobalMessage message={this.state.global_message.message} type={this.state.global_message.type} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And my `global-message.jsx`:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='global-message-wrap'>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName='global-message'>
                    <p className='global-message-text' key={this.props.message}>{this.props.message}</p>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This all works ok, and when I do `trigger` my `Backbone` event, everything updates fine.

HOWEVER.

If this is the React Way™ then so be it, but to me, having the state for a component stored in the parent feels unnatural. To me, if I have a `global-message` module, then I should be able to initialise it, and then hold its own data?

How else could I approach this/tidy this up?

Comment: You can move subscribe logic to your global message component, and depends on state return `null` (if nothing to show) or your message. You need to store the state in the parent component only if parent or other of its children also use this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment above.
If your global message state is used only by your `global-message.jsx` component, you can move all subscribe logic to this component:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            message: 'error',
            type: ''
        };
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        Backbone.on('global-message', function(data) {
            this.setState(data);
        }.bind(this));
    },        
    render: function() {
        if (!this.state.type) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className='global-message-wrap'>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName='global-message'>
                    <p className='global-message-text' key={this.state.message}>{this.state.message}</p>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And you can use your component without any props everywhere:

```
var React = require('react');
var Backbone = require('backbone');

var GlobalMessage = require('./shared/global-message.jsx');
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <GlobalMessage />
        );
    }
});
```

But if some state is shared between some children of the component, it is better to store the state in their parent component, something like this:

```
var UserInfoComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return api.getCurrentUser(); // {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith', avatar: 'http://...'}
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        // subscribe logic here
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        // unsubscribe logic here
    }
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <UserAvatarComponent avatar={this.state.avatar} />
                <UserMenuComponent user={this.state} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And other variant of usage parent component as data provider: For example you have and `ErrorMessageComponent` which encapsulates some code for displaying some error messages. So it is better to keep this component clean and reusable by avoiding data-fetching inside component and leave this logic for it's parents'. So, in different cases you will be able to use one component to show different errors by providing info to the component using props.